# Getting a connection string

Tags: c#, connection-string

The program I'm writing accesses a database. So when I use the SqlConnection() class, I hard code the actual connection string as a parameter. Eventually I'd like o deploy this program to different users. So my question is:

When a user installs a program on their computer, how does the new connection string get created, where is it stored, and how can I access it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Since you are writing the program, you may choose and design it. It does not happen automatically.

Comment: C# has a few drawbacks where connection strings are concerned. Try looking at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936392/mysql-securestring-as-connection-string/18150784#18150784

Answer (score 2):

You need to out it in a configuration file and load it from there. For an ASP.NET application it would be in the web.config file;

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="MyConnectionString" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

and then use

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString
```

in your application.

The for each installation it would be configured for the local requirements.

For a desktop application the details are different but the principle is the same.

See references in answer from Luis Sagasta

Answer (score 1):

As explained in MSDN, you should save the connection string in the configuration file:
[MSDN: Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx)

In the same article you will find information about encrypting the configuration section:
[MSDN:Encrypting Configuration File Sections Using Protected Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx#Anchor_2)

Regards.